# Weird samba and gvfs behavior - ~half of directories/files randomly appears to be "missing"

Tags: ubuntu, samba, gvfs

*The situation:* Server with Gentoo Linux and Samba on it. There's around 15 Windows PCs, one MacBook Pro and one Samsung's laptop with Ubuntu. There's no domain, just a workgroup and the server is used only for Samba shares. On Ubuntu I use gvfs to mount samba shares.

*And the problem:* One day around half of directories went missing, but only when viewing on this Ubuntu laptop. If I ssh to the server I can see the missing files/dirs and I can also see the missing things from win or mac computers.

*The tempfix:* When I rename some of the missing directories, even if it's one symbol, missing directories reappear … even without reloading/refreshing the gvfs-mounted share. If I rename instantly back to the previous directories/file names, all previously missing dirs/files instantly go missing again.

So, as this problem reappeared again around month later, I could use some advice where to start checking.

Answer (score 1):

I might have experienced similar problem, but just with single file missing.
I suspect, that linux samba mount helper is problematic.

Could you run following tests on your client?

```
cd [dir-with-missing-subdirs]

ls -al | grep [missing name]     -> nothing found (readdir is broken)
ls -al [missing name]            -> lists the element (stat working) -- use -d when [missing name] is a directory

To find out if kernel is hiding those files from you:

umount smb-share
start "tcpdump -p -i [your nic] -s0 -w net.dump host [your samba host]"
mount the share
run the "ls -al | grep [missing name]" test
stop tcpdump
Verify that the filename is in tcpdump, but not shown in dirlisting. Therefore:
strings --encoding=b net.dump | grep [missing name]
strings --encoding=l net.dump | grep [missing name]
```

If name is included at least once, that would indicate, that the samba server is sending the whole listing, but linux discards some entries.

Comment: I will try this out when this problem reappears or if I can reproduce the symptoms as described in the link you provided.